# Running Flutter on IOS Issue

Tags: android, ios, xcode, flutter

Below is the issue I am facing whenever I try to run my Flutter Application on IOS simulator:

---

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.11.13, on Mac OS X 10.14 18A391, locale en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Still facing the same errors. If anyone can help with the fix.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone XR in debug mode...

Starting Xcode build...

Xcode build done.                                            2.7s

Failed to build iOS app

Error output from Xcode build:

↳

    ** BUILD FAILED **



Xcode's output:

↳

    /Users/kamal369/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.6.6/ios/Classes/FirebaseAuthPlugin.m:76:41: error: incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(FIRAuthDataResult *__strong, NSError *__strong)' to parameter of type 'FIRAuthResultCallback _Nullable' (aka 'void (^)(FIRUser * _Nullable __strong, NSError * _Nullable __strong)')

            signInAnonymouslyWithCompletion:^(FIRAuthDataResult *dataResult, NSError *error) {

                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    In module 'FirebaseAuth' imported from /Users/kamal369/AndroidStudioProjects/tester_flutter/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:13:

    /Users/kamal369/AndroidStudioProjects/tester_flutter/ios/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Frameworks/FirebaseAuth.framework/Headers/FIRAuth.h:493:73: note: passing argument to parameter 'completion' here

    - (void)signInAnonymouslyWithCompletion:(nullable FIRAuthResultCallback)completion;

                                                                            ^

    /Users/kamal369/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.6.6/ios/Classes/FirebaseAuthPlugin.m:117:29: error: incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(FIRAuthDataResult *__strong, NSError *__strong)' to parameter of type 'FIRAuthResultCallback _Nullable' (aka 'void (^)(FIRUser * _Nullable __strong, NSError * _Nullable __strong)')

                     completion:^(FIRAuthDataResult *dataResult, NSError *error) {

                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    In module 'FirebaseAuth' imported from /Users/kamal369/AndroidStudioProjects/tester_flutter/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:13:

    /Users/kamal369/AndroidStudioProjects/tester_flutter/ios/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Frameworks/FirebaseAuth.framework/Headers/FIRAuth.h:590:61: note: passing argument to parameter 'completion' here

                     completion:(nullable FIRAuthResultCallback)completion;

                                                                ^

    /Users/kamal369/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.6.6/ios/Classes/FirebaseAuthPlugin.m:154:25: error: incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(FIRAuthDataResult *__strong, NSError *__strong)' to parameter of type 'FIRAuthResultCallback _Nullable' (aka 'void (^)(FIRUser * _Nullable __strong, NSError * _Nullable __strong)')

                 completion:^(FIRAuthDataResult *dataResult, NSError *error) {

                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    In module 'FirebaseAuth' imported from /Users/kamal369/AndroidStudioProjects/tester_flutter/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:13:

    /Users/kamal369/AndroidStudioProjects/tester_flutter/ios/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Frameworks/FirebaseAuth.framework/Headers/FIRAuth.h:372:57: note: passing argument to parameter 'completion' here

                 completion:(nullable FIRAuthResultCallback)completion;

                                                            ^

    /Users/kamal369/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.6.6/ios/Classes/FirebaseAuthPlugin.m:305:31: error: incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(FIRAuthDataResult *__strong, NSError *__strong)' to parameter of type 'FIRAuthResultCallback _Nullable' (aka 'void (^)(FIRUser * _Nullable __strong, NSError * _Nullable __strong)')

                       completion:^(FIRAuthDataResult *dataResult, NSError *error) {

                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    In module 'FirebaseAuth' imported from /Users/kamal369/AndroidStudioProjects/tester_flutter/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:13:

    /Users/kamal369/AndroidStudioProjects/tester_flutter/ios/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Frameworks/FirebaseAuth.framework/Headers/FIRAuth.h:537:63: note: passing argument to parameter 'completion' here

                       completion:(nullable FIRAuthResultCallback)completion;

                                                                  ^

    /Users/kamal369/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.6.6/ios/Classes/FirebaseAuthPlugin.m:392:62: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]

      userData[@"lastSignInTimestamp"] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:lastSignInDate];

                                         ~                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    1 warning and 4 errors generated.


Could not build the application for the simulator.

Error launching application on iPhone XR.
```

Comment: Try running `flutter clean` in your project directory and `pod install` in `ios/`

Answer (score 0):

It seems there might some kind of "out of date" problem with the Firebase pods.
For me, the solution proposed by Günter Zöchbauer worked fine: flutter clean in your project directory and pod install in ios/

There is another answer at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17721 that works for other developers, running the following commands in your project directory:
- pod repo update
- sudo gem install cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue related to your flutter channel. You can try this,

- cd to your project location from the terminal
- Execute `flutter channel`. Make sure `master` is selected (* indicates which one is selected)
- If `master` is not selected, execute `flutter channel master` to select `master`
- Execute `flutter clean`
- Execute `flutter run`

This should fix the issue (at least it did for me).

Good luck!